# Implementing Facebook comments plugin in ReactJS app

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to load the facebook comments plugin in a ReactJS app that's currently using React Router.

If I put the facebook init code inside my page's componentDidMount() method, it loads the first time.  But after going to another page and then going back to it again, it doesn't load the plugin at all.

Is there something that I need to do to make it appear all the time?

I'm thinking I need to remove the facebook init and reinitialize again.  But that doesn't feel right.

Any suggestions?  Below is my code of my component

```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SlidingPanels from '../components/SlidingPanels';

export class Feedback extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $(window).scrollTo(0, '0.5s');

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '115517331888071',
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.5' // use version 2.1
            });
        }.bind(this);

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cna.net.au/" data-numposts="10"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

``

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to initialize the JavaScript SDK once, and since `componentDidMount` only gets called once it´s fine where it is. Try putting [`FB.XFBML.parse()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) in `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can place `FB.XFBML.parse()` in `componentDidUpdate()` but it works only when component updates as `componentDidUpdate()` is a update life cycle method. This solution won't work if you navigate to some other component and then come back to it. Because in this case, `componentDidMount()` called again but not componentDidUpdate. So, its better to place `FB.XFBML.parse()` in top of `componentDidMount()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if(window.FB){
    FB.XFBML.parse();
  }
// all other code is same
}
```