# Facebook Social Plugins comments section hidden by classname (ReactJS)

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I'm using ReactJS (developped by Facebook) and I'm currently having issues displaying a Comment secton from Facebook Social Plugins... kind of ironic but hey, they haven't made a plugins themselft for react.

Anyway, I have inserted the diffent element in my code to add the comment section. When I'm loading the page, I can see the section is loading! (for less than a second) but it desappear quite rapidly. I checked the code generated by facebook and I found that it was adding in the class of my element : FB_hide_iframes. I tried removing it and the section was showing in my page!

The problem is that I don't know how to control the class added to my component.

[As you can see, the comments section is present, but it is hidden by the class FB_hide_iframes which i haven't put there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nya3.png)

Here's the code to add the section in my home page (home.js)

```
componentDidMount() { 
...
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6'
        });
    };
    (function (d, s, id) {
        console.log('test');
        const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        const js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=XXXXXXXX';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    FB.XFBML.parse(); 
...
}
```

and in the render function I added :

```
render() {
<div id="fb-root"></div>
...
<div className="fb-comments"
                    data-href="MY-URL"
                    data-width="1000"
                    data-numposts="10"
                    data-order-by="reverse_time">
                </div>
```

Anyone got an idea?

Edit: 
The comments section is showing, but when I go in another section of my website and comeback (Single-page App), it Disappears.
Here's the code of my component :

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { mediaQueries } from '../../decorators';

@mediaQueries
export default class FacebookComments extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
    mediaQueries: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    appId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    version: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

state = {
    mobile: false,
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.mediaQueries('(max-width: 950px)', () => {
        this.setState({
            mobile: true,
        });
    });
    this.props.mediaQueries('(min-width: 951px)', () => {
        this.setState({
            mobile: false,
        });
    });

        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6',
        });

    (function (d, s, id) {
        const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        const js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}

componentDidUpate() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}

render() {
    const componentWidth = this.state.mobile ? '95%' : '75%';

    return (
        <div style={{ width: componentWidth }}>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <div className="fb-comments"
                data-href={this.props.url}
                data-width="100%"
                data-numposts="10"
                data-order-by="reverse_time">
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

luschn I don't know and don't understand what you are saying. I put a console.log in fbAsyncInit and it never showed, which mean it never get called. I looked online and there's no information about it. People online only say : Put that in you code and let the magic happen.....
That's why I removed it from my code. 
Edit #2 : All I have for Facebook Social Plugin is in this code.

Comment: if fbAsyncInit never gets called, then the js sdk never gets loaded. maybe this tutorials helps you to understand what´s happening with the js sdk: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: you should never just copy and paste code, always make sure you understand every single bit of it. the js sdk gets loaded asynchronously, and fbAsyncInit tells you exactly when it is loaded. only after that, you can use "FB" (which is basically the js sdk).

Comment: so...i don´t even see fbAsyncInit in your last code part...?

Comment: it was around FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6',
        });

Comment: edited my answer with the full code. if that does not work, please check your browser console for errors.

Comment: [no error](https://gyazo.com/fa4a9138b72182d107425c5718a94fff) As you can see, there is no problem in the console, my code is the same as the one you just added in your answer. The comment section is suppose to be under the ad.

Comment: check out my last edit in the answer. the issue seems to be the route change, back to the component. i am sorry, but i guess i understand now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side Note: It is a terrible idea to add the JS SDK init code in `componentDidMount`. Instead, add that code to your base HTML or put it in a separate "init" function and make sure it´s loaded before using the component.

Either way, you can only use `FB.XFBML.parse` after `FB.init` - that is, when the JS SDK is loaded and initialized:

```js
FB.init({
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.6'
});
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

You should even have a warning or error in the browser onsole that FB is not defined with your current code.

You may also need to call `FB.XFBML.parse()` again in `componentDidUpdate`.

That being said, here´s my idea of it:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxx',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6'
        });
        FB.XFBML.parse();
        console.log('make sure this happens');
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        let js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```

Again, you should put that init/loading stuff elsewhere, but that´s just for optimization. Check your browser console for errors, it may be possible that `componentDidUpdate` gets called before the JS SDK is initialized. In that case, you may need to check if FB is available:

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (FB) {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a state variable ("isSDKInitialized", for example) and set it to true after FB.init:

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.isSDKInitialized) {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

**That´s the minimum you need, the problem with routing is that both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` will not get called. Try with `componentWillReceiveProps` in addition (same code as in `componentDidUpdate` to refresh the Social Plugins).**

Check out those links for more information - assuming you are using `react-router`:

- https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/527
- https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md

Comment: It works when i removed window.fbAsyncInit = function () {} around the init! Thanks! JS SDK in componentDidMount seems okay if I look at another answer you gave :P  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653455/implementing-facebook-comments-plugin-in-reactjs-app)

Comment: you do need fbAsyncInit somewhere in your code, and you must call FB.init after the js sdk was initialized. but the main information is to use FB.XFBML.parse after FB.init.

Comment: I have another problem. When I change page and comeback, the section is hidding just like the problem I first have. I'm doing a single page app so there is no reload. I havE FB.XFBML.parse() after the init, in the componentDidUpdate(). I cannot put the JS SDK init code at the beginning of my <body> because i get parsing error.

Comment: what parsing error? you need to be more specific. a test link would be a good idea. about the page comeback: that´s why i mentioned componentDidUpdate in my answer.

Comment: anyway, adding the js sdk loading code after the body tag may not be useful for react apps too. you really need to understand when stuff is available, especially in react with all the lifecycle functions. FB.init will ONLY be available when the js sdk is loaded, the async callback MUST have been called BEFORE componentDidMount - for example, you can just create a service to load the js sdk and use it in componentDidMount.

Comment: again, to make this 100% clear: FB.init MUST be called AFTER fbAsyncInit got called. make sure that happens correctly.

Comment: edited the code. should be obvious, but make sure to try this on a real server (either localhost or public).

Comment: oooh, wait a minute, i think i misunderstood. my bad, componentDidUpdate will not really work here for page switching, because it does not get called for that - only if props or state changes ;) - let me edit my answer again.

Comment: fbAsyncInit is still never called anywhere. I added the FB.XGBML.parse() in componentWillReceivedProps() too. Right now, nothing is showing because I don't have a FB.init out of the fbAsyncInit. Also this : [FB is not defined](https://gyazo.com/5190db2deeb25ec7533ce5a7471fe908)

Comment: yes, that means that the JS SDK is not loaded and you are trying to use FB before it is. i am using pretty much the same code in my projects and fbAsyncInit works perfectly fine. can you put a test link online?

Comment: btw, i have to ask again: are you trying on a REAL server? (localhost or public), or are you trying by opening the html file directly in your browser, without a server?

Comment: Since the beginning. I am running it on localhost. I don't think i can put a test link online (for my job...) I need to say that right now, nothing is showing because i removed any FB.init from anywhere outside the fbAsyncInit

Comment: well, first you need to make sure that fbAsyncInit gets called. and FB.init should only be called right after that happened. without a test link it´s really hard, you should always try to add a testable minimal example to your question. that would make things a LOT easier.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/0grgS

The console.log in the function(d,s,id) {} are displaying in the console.
Use this page to chat.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to correct the bug. You must NOT have  :                 `<script src="//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/sdk.js"></script>`
in your `<head>`, you MUST have  `<div id="fb-root"></div>` at the beginning of the `<body>` and this code in your FacebookComments Component :

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.props.mediaQueries('(max-width: 950px)', () => {
            this.setState({
                mobile: true
            });
        });
        this.props.mediaQueries('(min-width: 951px)', () => {
            this.setState({
                mobile: false
            });
        });

    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
        FB.init({
            appId: this.props.appId,
            xfbml: true,
            version: this.props.version,
        });
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    };
    (function (d, s, id) {
        const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        const js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}

componentWillReceiveProps() {
    if (FB) {
        console.log('its in receiveProps');
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}

componentDidUpate() {
    if (FB) {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

This me code however is giving me one error, but it doesn't stop the webapp from loading the comments section. You propably will get a : 
`Unhandled promise rejection ReferenceError: FB is not defined(…)`
I tried to make a flag with a element of the state, but it isnt the same state from before.