# FaceBook Comment Plugin is not showing correctly when using with React

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to integrate FaceBook comment plugin into a React project. It works fine but when I navigate away and comeback the comment section disappear. When I refresh the page it reappear again, I have tried this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355637/facebook-social-plugins-comments-section-hidden-by-classname-reactjs) but it doesn't work. Here's my code

```
componentDidMount(){
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  window.FB.init({
    appId            : 'xxxxxxxxx',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v3.0'
  });
  window.FB.XFBML.parse();
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 }

 componentDidUpdate(){
 window.FB.XFBML.parse();
 }
```

I also get this error in the console when the comment section doesn't show up

```
    1_DH1qU_x8k.js:57 ErrorUtils caught an error: "Blocked a frame 
    with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a cross...". 
    Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
```

When I refresh the page the error goes away and everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the call to **( function(d, s, id){ } (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk")** outside the scope of componentDidMount(). Add it inside the componentDidMount() function and it should work.

Here is the working code

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  window.FB.init({
    appId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v3.0'
   });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
   var js,
     fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");
}  

componentDidUpdate() {
   window.FB.XFBML.parse();
 }
```